# Laravel 4 installing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hi I have uploaded laravel 4 to my ftp but for some reason on my domain just says

Index of /

```
.gitattributes
.gitignore
CONTRIBUTING.md
app/
artisan
bootstrap/
cgi-bin/
composer.json
phpunit.xml
public/
readme.md
server.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must point your domain to

```
/your/app/dir/public
```

It's now pointing to

```
/your/app/dir
```

And you don't have a vendor folder in it, so you also have to execute

```
cd /your/app/dir

composer install
```

Comment: That not good should be able to use ftp direct like codeigniter. So once I do that via wamp. then upload it to ftp then can it work?